# Anything like export-add for gitattribute?

Tags: git, archive, gitattributes

How can I overwrite an excluded folder in `.gitignore`, by adding it when I generate my archive with `git-archive`?

There is `export-ignore`, but it can't find anything like `export-add``export-include`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this makes no sense. As a complete guess, are you wanting `git archive` to include things in the archive file that `git` is not tracking because they're in `.gitignore`? If that's the case, I don't think it's directly possible, but you could always add things to the archive after it's been created...

Comment: well, that's exactly what I am trying to do. I was doing so until now, by having an orphan branch, but I would like to stop worrying about the merge between branches.